# ASP VB.NET Repeater in Repeater?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following SQL Tables.

**tCategory**

idCategory | catName

**tLink**

idLink | Url | FK_Category

On my ASP.NET site I want to do this:

CategoryOne

- www.google.com
- www.wikipedia.com

CategoryTwo

- www.stackoverflow.com
- www.myawesomewebsite.com

CategoryThree

- www.wordlwideweb.com

How can I do this dynamically. I'm thinking of two repeaters.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, but yes - two nested repeaters looks like a good solution. In a webforms project, it is what I would do.

Just fetch your data, bind it to the first repeater and use linq to extract the data for the inner repeater.

Comment: Or maybe a repeater which has a gridview inside, might be easier. Depents on what kind of markup you are looking for.